# Tick Intervals: Changing it from the default

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-plot

So I am trying to change the tick intervals of the x and y axis. But the default is counting up by .5. I want to change it to count up by tens. Please help. I have recently tried something like this but had no luck.

```
xMajorInterval = 10;
yMajorInterval = 10;  
axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMajorInterval);
axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 4.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 8.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset = 1.0f;

axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMajorInterval);
axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 4.0f;
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 8.0f;
axisSet.yAxis.labelOffset = 1.0f;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177737/core-plot-tick-intervals

Comment: Which labeling policy do your axes use? The default is `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval` which should be fine with the code you posted.